# add file tag programmatically to an image file in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, windows, image, macos

Is it possible to programmatically add file tag to a file of type image (png/jpeg) in iOS? I am using the camera to capture the image and am writing the data into a file in the Documents folder in my iOS app.
Then, i use the file sharing capability in iTunes to transfer the images out to my MAC or Windows Desktop.
After i export all the files in this fashion, i would like to sort the images by tag on my MAC or Windows Desktop.

The definition of tag in the MAC world is different than that of the Windows, it appears. But setting that difference aside for a moment, both MAC and Windows allow the user to manually assign some sort of a TAG to the file so that we can sort it and view it in Finder or File explorer applications respectively on those platforms.

So, the question is: In an iOS app, when i am creating an image file, can i programmatically assign some sort of tag which i can then leverage to sort on my MAC or Windows after i export those files.

Thanks for your time all.

Comment: what about sort by creation date

Comment: @Sh_Khan not an option. some images are more important than others. so, we have to sort NOT based on file size, file name or date. need some way to assign a priority outside of what's available standard.

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to add data to image files directly. Maybe you can use EXIF meta but not an ideal. What about using `hashValue` and keep the value locally?

Comment: @Ryan Can you explain how we can use hashValue to achieve the goal? Thanks.